# IE Image Positioning Issue

Tags: css, html

I am facing some IE issue for Image Position. http://hentschelco.com/Home/Team.aspx on this page the First profile is good but the rest of them Email and Phone Image are not in same position.

If I change the position for the Email and Phone image then it will be not the same position on Chrome, Safari, or Firefox.

Any advice please?

Thanks.

Comment: LOL making your copy into a code source... Can you add some code here or on fiddle? Be more specific like what IE version.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if the images are positioned with negative left margin percentages. These can be problematic in IE. Maybe try positioning the icons relatively inside of the div with the blue background, or use absolute positioning if that would work for your layout.